# Django Rest Framework - Using Reverse Relationships with __all__

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So, I completely get the use of reverse relationships in the serializer for Django Rest Framework. And I've successfully implemented a solution that gives me what I want to see in the data output.

However, the final implementation makes me a little unhappy.

Essentially, I wanted to have an API result that gave me complete nested information of my related model - so Modules with all its fields and then its reverse relationship, SubModules, with all its fields.

So, in my example, in order we have `Modules` which in turn have many `SubModules`.

The SubModules `models.py` has a relationship like:

```py
module = models.ForeignKey(Module, related_name='sub_modules')
```

Obviously, there is no direct sub_modules property defined in the Modules `models.py`.

So, in the Modules `serializer.py`, I wanted to make sure that the full `sub_modules` objects were returned in the API call to `/api/modules` - not URLs or IDs.

So, my initial implementation (not what I wanted) was something like:

```py
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

However, this returns the following (notice, no `sub_modules`):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-13T11:19:28.665000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-13T11:19:28.665000Z",
    "order": 1,
    "inactive": null,
    "name": "Module 1",
    "description": "Module 1",
    "price": "100.0000000000"
},
```

The implementation that eventually worked (but whose pattern I'm not happy with) was something like:

```py
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'order', 'inactive',
                  'price', 'name', 'description', 'sub_modules')
        depth = 1
```

This, correctly, gave me:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-02-13T11:19:28.665000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-13T11:19:28.665000Z",
    "order": 1,
    "inactive": null,
    "price": "100.0000000000",
    "name": "Module 1",
    "description": "Module 1",
    "sub_modules": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-02-13T14:16:00.478429Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-13T14:16:00.478471Z",
            "order": 1,
            "inactive": null,
            "name": "SubModule 1",
            "description": "SubModule 1",
            "price": "100.0000000",
            "module": 1
        }
    ]
},
```

#### Why don't I like this pattern?

The thing that makes Django Rest Framework my goto REST implementation of choice (over say, Flask RESTful for example) is that I can usually rely on my pattern involving DRY code and the implementation of consistent single sources of truth.

I want to be able to keep my data layer where it should be - at my model level and change only that and have it feedback, by default, to the serializer. Obviously, then I'd manage exceptions on the serializer level when I want the data to transform or be absent or whatever (a good example is keeping the `password` field off of the users endpoint data).

If I have to maintain the fields value in the `Meta` class, I'm inherently managing two sources of truth for my Modules entity.

#### What I'd like to be able to do

I'd like my `sub_modules` object to be returned by default by the `fields = '__all__'` expression. But, it's explicitly stated, this isn't done by default in the DRF docs.

So, I tried a couple of implementations of a manual `sub_modules` field on the Modules `serializer.py` (an acceptable implementation in my opinion since it is a reverse relationship).

Remember, the following are on the Modules `serializer.py`:

#### RelatedField

```py
sub_modules = serializers.RelatedField()
```

Result

AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

#### RelatedField - with some params

```py
sub_modules = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)
```

Result

NotImplementedError at /modules/
RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field sub_modules

Say what??

#### So, what is my final question?

Basically, I'm looking for a pattern that allows me to link my serializer to my model AND include the reverse relationships in a manner where I don't have to define my field specification explicitly on the `serializer.py`.

I'm the biggest advocate of explicit over implicit but, the model is quite explicit enough, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a serializer for SubModules with fields set to **all**. Then, refer to this serializer from your ModuleSerializer like so:

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  sub_modules = SubModuleSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
      fields = '__all __'
      model = Modules
      depth = 1
  ...
```

This should give you the nested representation that you are looking for while preserving a DRY format.

Haven't actually tried this out but should work

Comment: Ah, how did I overlook that!!!! This was similar to one of my previous iterations. Except, I think I left out the `many=True` param. Which gave me an error 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'pk'. So I dismissed it as an option.

Thanks!